# Is there any disadvantage of using Map over Object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, hashtable

Are there any noticeable benefits of using Object over ES6's `Map()`? I like using it for the `forEach` function. Is it a bad practice to opt for `Map()` when needing hash tables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The case of `Object` vs `Map` in the context of Javascript is more of a question of whether you want a generic or specialized tool for the job.

`Map` is actually just a special kind of object (just like any other type of object that you would construct in your application. You could even make your own `Map()` constructor function to mimic ES6 Maps). Like other objects, it has methods to access its functionalities. The "specialty" of the `Map` is to be an efficient key-value store.

The `Object` on the other hand is one of Javascripts native data types, and can be used for a variety of purposes (`Map` being one of them). It is not "specialized" for any one purpose.

So, in conclusion :

- If you are using a `Map` as an efficient hash table, **go for it**! That's what it's built for.
- If you are using `Map` for anything other than a key value store (or, as you say, *just* because of the `forEach` method) you may have to reconsider using it in favour of a more suitable data structure (which may or may not be a plain old object)

Comment: ...and vice versa - if you're using Objects as hash tables, stop doing that!

Answer (score 0):

There is a good explanation on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) as to when and why prefer `Map` over `Object`.

To sum it up:

- Map has **useful properties, utility functions and is Iterable**, which
  saves you some writing compared to using Object (like while trying to find number of key-value pairs)
- **Map can be more performant** in intensive key-value operations (adition, removal)
- Map prevents unwanted collisions between your keys and predefined Object's prototype properties
- Map can use objects for keys